# Real time windowed counters using kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I would like to have a real-time efficient system to perform real-time windowed counters of event. For example, number of clicks per country in the last 30 minutes. My idea is the following, using Kafka and Cassandra:

when a click event *e* happens at time *t*, an increment is sent to an accumulator (I would like to use Cassandra counters for this purpose); at the same time, this event should generate a decrement event at time *t+30min*, which basically marks the exit of the event e from the window of interest. This decrement will be then stored in the accumulator at time *t+30min*. Querying the accumulator at any time will then give the current correct counter value

I am not sure how to achieve this using Kafa. I thought about 2 approaches

1. clicks are sent to topic C; a consumer will read from C and produce events in a topic *Cdelayed* with message (*Tdelay*, *key*); another consumer will read from *Cdelayed* and check the content of the first message read: if the timestamp in the message is equal or after the current time, then the message is read and the decrement is sent to the accumulator
2. a main consumer will poll from *C* and when performing the first read will trigger a delayed consumer which will sleep 30 minutes before start reading from earliest timestamp; the latter will be responsible for decrements, the former for increments

Which of the 2 solutions is the best? Am I using Kafka API in the correct way if I 1) block a consumer or 2) delay a consumer?

Comment: Why not try Kafka Streams windows?

Comment: I have a large volume of data, I think that windowing will work but it might generate a big pressure on the stream application memory. The approach above looks to me conceptually simpler.

Comment: Kafka Streams spills to disk using RocksDB, if you configure it to. So, memory shouldn't be as much as concern as also storage

Comment: how would the kafka stream application look like? What window size should I use? I don't see an immediate way of dealing with future events here too

Comment: I don't have an off-hand example, but I was just suggesting using that library rather than trying to redo it using a plain consumer. And there are different types of windows and when you want to process them can be a sliding or hoping window, for example, so 5 minutes of data wouldn't be processed until the end of that starting window time, for example.

Comment: Yep, use Kafka Streams for this